# App submission to App Store: Developer reject

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted the binary file of my application to apple on appstore.

But I didn't configure the APP ID. Does it will affect my application for apple submission?

Should I do a developer reject and if I do that Can I upload the new binary ..?

Please reply me as soon as possible I don't want my application to get rejected by apple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you didn't configure the App ID, do you mean the Bundle Identifier? You can replace the binary once you reject it. Just note that a developer reject will move your app to the back of the queue

Comment: i have configured the bundle identifier. But after that we need to configure it i.e tick a option app store submission .I have not done that

Answer (score 2):

Rejecting your own app is a rite of passage, it won't hurt future submissions.  Reject it, fix it, resubmit it.

Answer (score 2):

Before your app can be reviewed, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Binary Architecture - iOS 3.0 introduced support for multiple binary architectures. If your binary is built for multiple architectures, your Info.plist must have a MinimumOSVersion key with a value of at least 3.0. Additionally, if your app is intended to support earlier iPhone and iPod touch models, your app must contain at least an armv6 binary; "thin" armv7-only binaries will not be accepted unless the armv7 required device capability is also present in the Info.plist UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key or the MinimumOSVersion key has a value of 4.3 or higher.

For more information, see Technical Q&A QA1707 at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1707.html.

Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission process until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.

This Solution will surely help you to upload your App on iTunes.